# Error occurs randomly "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, cryptography

I have ASP.net MVC application that runs on Microsoft-IIS/8.5 dedicated virtual server
The application runs smoothly till its randomly raise the following error for the users on login

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.

and only solution to get rid of the error is to restart the iis

Error Details

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
   at System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.HomogenizeErrors(Func`2 func, Byte[] input)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.SecureDataFormat`1.Protect(TData data)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseGrantAsync>d__f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseCoreAsync>d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<TeardownAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.<DoFinalWork>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

What I did to solve the problem as answers on similar issues

1. add the following tag to web.config

2. added fixed machineKey even the application is on a dedicated server
   and not on a shared or load balancing environment
3. changed the login mechanism to be like the following

```
 var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
 AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
                        {
                            AllowRefresh = true,
                            IsPersistent = false,
                            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
                        }, identity);
```

But all solutions were useless and the error keeps come up every a period of time and I had to restart the IIS to get rid of it .

Thank you for any suggestions.

**Edit**

```
<error application="/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT" host="STS" type="System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException" message="Error occurred during a cryptographic operation." source="System.Web" detail="System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation. at System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.HomogenizeErrors(Func`2 func, Byte[] input) at Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.SecureDataFormat`1.Protect(TData data) at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseGrantAsync>d__f.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseCoreAsync>d__b.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseAsync>d__8.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<TeardownAsync>d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__7.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.<DoFinalWork>d__12.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)" time="2021-07-16T07:34:44.0788126Z" class=" FB_FW_ext EyeBankWeb">
<serverVariables>
<item name="ALL_HTTP">
<value string="HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL:max-age=0 HTTP_CONNECTION:keep-alive HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH:58 HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE:application/x-www-form-urlencoded HTTP_ACCEPT:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3 HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gzip, deflate, br HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:en-US,en;q=0.9 HTTP_COOKIE:culture=ar; ASP.NET_SessionId=ushubsqlqwfllhv4moavnl1j HTTP_HOST:sts.gedco.ps HTTP_REFERER:https://sts.gedco.ps/Users/login?ReturnUrl=%2F HTTP_USER_AGENT:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36 HTTP_MACHINEID:6F4B-514D-040C-79A4-C233-51D5-03FC-602A HTTP_ORIGIN:https://sts.gedco.ps HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS:1 HTTP_VERSION:1.1.0.0 "/>
</item>
<item name="ALL_RAW">
<value string="Cache-Control: max-age=0 Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 58 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9 Cookie: culture=ar; ASP.NET_SessionId=ushubsqlqwfllhv4moavnl1j Host: sts.gedco.ps Referer: https://sts.gedco.ps/Users/login?ReturnUrl=%2F User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36 MACHINEID: 6F4B-514D-040C-79A4-C233-51D5-03FC-602A Origin: https://sts.gedco.ps Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 VERSION: 1.1.0.0 "/>
</item>
<item name="APPL_MD_PATH">
<value string="/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT"/>
</item>
<item name="APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH">
<value string="C:\WebSites\Vending\"/>
</item>
<item name="AUTH_TYPE">
<value string=""/>
</item>
<item name="AUTH_USER">
<value string=""/>
</item>
<item name="AUTH_PASSWORD">
<value string="*****"/>
</item>
<item name="LOGON_USER">
<value string=""/>
</item>
<item name="REMOTE_USER">
<value string=""/>
</item>
<item name="CERT_COOKIE">
<value string=""/>
</item>
<item name="CERT_FLAGS">
<value string=""/>
</item>
<item name="CERT_ISSUER">
<value string=""/>
</item>
<item name="CERT_KEYSIZE">
<value string="256"/>
</item>
<item name="CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE">
<value string="2048"/>
</item>
<item name="CERT_SERIALNUMBER">
<value string=""/>
</item>
<item name="CERT_SERVER_ISSUER">
<value string="C=US, S=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2"/>
</item>
<item name="CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT">
<value string="OU=Domain Control Validated, CN=*.gedco.ps"/>
</item>
<item name="CERT_SUBJECT">
<value string=""/>
</item>
<item name="CONTENT_LENGTH">
<value string="58"/>
</item>
<item name="CONTENT_TYPE">
<value string="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
</item>
<item name="GATEWAY_INTERFACE">
<value string="CGI/1.1"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTPS">
<value string="on"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTPS_KEYSIZE">
<value string="256"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE">
<value string="2048"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER">
<value string="C=US, S=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT">
<value string="OU=Domain Control Validated, CN=*.gedco.ps"/>
</item>
<item name="INSTANCE_ID">
<value string="2"/>
</item>
<item name="INSTANCE_META_PATH">
<value string="/LM/W3SVC/2"/>
</item>
<item name="LOCAL_ADDR">
<value string="192.168.130.6"/>
</item>
<item name="PATH_INFO">
<value string="/Users/Login"/>
</item>
<item name="PATH_TRANSLATED">
<value string="C:\WebSites\Vending\Users\Login"/>
</item>
<item name="QUERY_STRING">
<value string=""/>
</item>
<item name="REMOTE_ADDR">
<value string="188.161.225.73"/>
</item>
<item name="REMOTE_HOST">
<value string="188.161.225.73"/>
</item>
<item name="REMOTE_PORT">
<value string="12163"/>
</item>
<item name="REQUEST_METHOD">
<value string="POST"/>
</item>
<item name="SCRIPT_NAME">
<value string="/Users/Login"/>
</item>
<item name="SERVER_NAME">
<value string="sts.gedco.ps"/>
</item>
<item name="SERVER_PORT">
<value string="443"/>
</item>
<item name="SERVER_PORT_SECURE">
<value string="1"/>
</item>
<item name="SERVER_PROTOCOL">
<value string="HTTP/1.1"/>
</item>
<item name="SERVER_SOFTWARE">
<value string="Microsoft-IIS/8.5"/>
</item>
<item name="URL">
<value string="/Users/Login"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL">
<value string="max-age=0"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTP_CONNECTION">
<value string="keep-alive"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH">
<value string="58"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE">
<value string="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTP_ACCEPT">
<value string="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING">
<value string="gzip, deflate, br"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE">
<value string="en-US,en;q=0.9"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTP_COOKIE">
<value string="culture=ar; ASP.NET_SessionId=ushubsqlqwfllhv4moavnl1j"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTP_HOST">
<value string="sts.gedco.ps"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTP_REFERER">
<value string="https://sts.gedco.ps/Users/login?ReturnUrl=%2F"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTP_USER_AGENT">
<value string="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTP_MACHINEID">
<value string="6F4B-514D-040C-79A4-C233-51D5-03FC-602A"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTP_ORIGIN">
<value string="https://sts.gedco.ps"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS">
<value string="1"/>
</item>
<item name="HTTP_VERSION">
<value string="1.1.0.0"/>
</item>
</serverVariables>
<form>
<item name="ReturnUrl">
<value string="/"/>
</item>
<item name="PosId">
<value string="616"/>
</item>
<item name="UserName">
<value string="410026"/>
</item>
<item name="Password">
<value string="********"/>
</item>
</form>
<cookies>
<item name="culture">
<value string="ar"/>
</item>
<item name="ASP.NET_SessionId">
<value string="ushubsqlqwfllhv4moavnl1j"/>
</item>
</cookies>
</error>
```

Comment: Is there an InnerException with further details?

Comment: It is strange that restart IIS can solve this exception. Have you tried to clear cache and cookie of browser before access application? If you didnot log out correct before close browser, this issue may appear.

Comment: @MatthewWatson this all the exception details I have, I'm using elmah to log the errors, is there a way to log more exception details ?

Comment: @BruceZhang actually this error happens the same time to all users when they try to login

Comment: Do all users have this issue when they login for first time? Or just this error occurs for second, third login?

Comment: @BruceZhang I'm not sure if the already logged users face the same issue, but what I'm sure of it, is that any new user tries to login to the system the above exception is happening, the elmah only logging exception for the users are trying login to system

Comment: Besides stack trace, can you give more detailed error information? This information will contain the specific code or content of the problem. In addition, can you give me more code about the identity, ClaimsIdentity part? According to the existing code, I think it is no problem. But it can't be ruled out completely, more code is needed.

Comment: @BruceZhang I've added more error details, can you please take a look?

Comment: Please delete the UserTokenCaches table entries from the database.

Comment: @BruceZhang I don't even use UserTokenCaches table

Comment: The error details you added is same as the first one. Doesn't the error page show the problem code? Please post the whole code of login.